# Can you create a custom reducer?

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

For a specific size of area (e.g. 1km squared), I want to apply formulas to a feature collection.

These formulas aren't included in the reducers available. For example, I want to get the circular mean and circular variance of the angles of the edges of polygons in each 1km squared, while reducers just include regular mean and variance.

Is there any way for me to make my own reducer? Or to achieve this some other way?

For context: Here is the code I use to apply the formulas to a specific area https://code.earthengine.google.com/6600a883f18100443ca33635f4c3e71d, now I want to generalize that area to each 1km squared in a region.

Comment: No, you can't create a custom reducer.  But assuming you had the appropriate reducer, how would you expect to do this?  map over a big collection of 1km cells, doing a filterBounds for each?

Comment: I was thinking reduceToImage using that reducer and a 1000m scale - would that work?

Comment: It might work if you had a feature per edge, each with an angle (do-able; you just need to map over the buildings producing a collection of edges/angles); but once you have that, you can just do the circular mean math yourself by summing the sines and cosines of the angle into the image directly.

Comment: I did what you suggested, and now have angles represented in an image. To sum the sines I use: sin_angles.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry: block, scale: 50}), is this correct?  I'm getting some strange results. The code can also be seen here (line 182): https://code.earthengine.google.com/e1850bf0d52f371da62755e4d92e4187

Comment: You can't reduce the angles into an image, you have to convert to sines and cosines and reduce those into an image by summing.

Comment: I've done that, but now I need to subtract the circle mean from angles in each area (to calculate the variance). And am running into trouble (e.g. can I do this without also converting angles into images?): https://code.earthengine.google.com/bae0bd9f1579ebd29e45239d00f89fda (line  196 throws the error)

Comment: You don't need to go back to the original angles to compute circular variance; you can get it as `1 - hypot(cos, sin)` (see: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/_modules/astropy/stats/circstats.html#circmean)  unless you want linear variance from the circular mean.  If you really want to subtract the image value from all the original angles instead, you need to reduceRegion to get the mean angle for each building (probably easiest to map over the original buildings and get it for each one)